# How to place an image in a drawn circle

Tags: c#

SO i have a drawn circle:

```
int playerwidth = 40; 
int playerheight = 40; 
int xPosp = 0;
int yPosp = 0;


System.Drawing.SolidBrush pen1 = new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.White);
e.Graphics.FillEllipse(pen1, xPosp, yPosp, playerwidth, playerheight);
```

And I have an image in my resources, How can I place the image in the circle.

Answer (score 1):

You need to search about how to know the largest rectangle in an ellipse (optimization problem).

```
private static void DrawInEllipse(Graphics g, Image img, Rectangle rect)
{
    //margin definition for rectangle image (2%)
    double marginX = rect.Width*0.02f;
    double marginY = rect.Height*0.02f;

    using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(img, rect.Size))
    using (var brush = new TextureBrush(bitmap))
    {
        //fill ellipse
        g.FillEllipse(Brushes.White, rect);

        //calculate image rectangle
        var w = rect.Width/Math.Sqrt(2d) - marginX;
        var h = rect.Height/Math.Sqrt(2d) - marginY;
        var x = (rect.Left + rect.Width/2d) - (w/2);
        var y = (rect.Top + rect.Height/2d) - (h/2);

        var imgRect = new RectangleF((float) x, (float) y, (float) w, (float) h);

        //daw image in rectangle
        g.FillRectangle(brush, imgRect);
    }
}
```

Assuming that `your_image` is the resource name, look how to use the above function:

```
...
int playerwidth = 40;
int playerheight = 40;
int xPosp = 0;
int yPosp = 0;

var rect = new Rectangle(xPosp, yPosp, playerwidth, playerheight);
DrawInEllipse(e.Graphics, Resources.your_image, rect);
...
```

I hope it helps.

[image: Probe]

Answer (score -1):

Resize the picture you want to place in the circle so that it fits into the circle, and then add a `PictureBox` to your form and add the picture you want to display to the `PictureBox`, set its location so that it's placed in the center of your circle like this:

EDIT:
Just add a `PictureBox` to your form and place it anywhere, this code should work.

```
private static void DrawInEllipse(PictureBox picBox, Image img, Rectangle rect)
{
    picBox.Width = rect.Width - (int)(rect.Width*0.3f);
    picBox.Height = rect.Height - (int)(rect.Width * 0.3f);        

    picBox.Image = img;
    picBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
    picBox.BackColor = Color.Transparent;

    int picCenterX = (rect.Width - picBox.Width) / 2 + rect.Location.X;
    int picCenterY = (rect.Height - picBox.Height) / 2 + rect.Location.Y;

    picBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(picCenterX, picCenterY);
}
```

As you can see no matter how big the image its size depends on the Height and Width of your ellipse, unlike dbvega's method where the size of the image is the same and has to be cropped in order to fit into the ellipse.
Also, using a `PictureBox` gives you many advantages such as assigning events to it, resizing it, moving it, etc.

Usage:

```
...
int playerWidth = 40;
int playerHeight = 40;
int xPosp = 0;
int yPosp = 0;

SolidBrush pen1 = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(xPosp, yPosp, playerWidth, playerHeight);
e.Graphics.FillEllipse(pen1, rect);

DrawInEllipse(pictureBox1, your_namespace.Properties.Resources.your_image, rect);
...
```

Comment: Your answer is not the better way to fill an ellipse using image resource. Also the picture box will display the image in rectangular shape. Check my answer.

Comment: He wanted the circle to be white, your way does not accomplish that. How would you resolve that? Yes the image will be in rectangulare shape that is why I added that he should set BackColor to Transparent.

Comment: Check his question again, he doesn't want to fill an ellipse with an image, he wants to add an image to an already filled ellipse. So maybe my answer is not the better way but it is more accurate than yours.

Comment: check my answer again please.

Comment: I have edited my answer. IMO there is no need to complicate things the way you did, besides I have tried your code and mine with the same image without editing it, your code does not produce good results.

Comment: I'm not complicated, I used Math to calculate the largest rectangle in an ellipse. Also I added a picture, the code works like a charm. You can change the `playerwidth, playerheight, xPosp and yPosp` as many times as you need. See the picture.